# Material UI form input element - fullwidth with formHelper and endAdornment

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Material UI form input elements.

I'm trying to use this input as a full width item, that uses both a form helper and and endAdornment.

I have tried both the Input and the InputBase options, but each of these seem to restrict this composition.

This [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-js9p3?file=/index.js) shows the width issue using the Input component.  Currently, the width container is set to fullWidth and the root class defines that as 90% - but the form input gets squished to a small size - and I can't see an attribute enforcing that.

When I try using the InputBase, i can have full width, but I can't use the form helper beneath the form input (it gets pushed onto the same line and appears after the InfoIcon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the input is occupying the full width of its parent container, which in this case is the `FormControl`, so you must make the `FormControl` wider to achieve what you want. For example, you can add a class to the `FormControl` and style it so it spans the full width of it container (see code below). You can see it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-26sgr?file=/form.js).

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: "2px 4px",
    // display: 'flex',
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "90%",
    margin: "auto"
  },
  input: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    flex: 1
  },
  iconButton: {
    padding: 10
  },
  divider: {
    height: 28,
    margin: 4
  },
  formControl: {
    width: "90%"
  }
}));

export default function ProposalDemoForm() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginLeft: "3vw" }} />
      <Paper component="form" className={classes.root} elevation={0}>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="component-helper">Title</InputLabel>
          <Input
            id="component-helper"
            placeholder={"name"}
            fullWidth={true}
            onChange={"handleChange"}
            aria-describedby="component-helper-text"
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <Divider className={classes.divider} orientation="vertical" />
                <IconButton
                  color="primary"
                  className={classes.iconButton}
                  aria-label="directions"
                >
                  <InfoIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
          <FormHelperText id="component-helper-text">
            <a href="link.com" className="bodylinks" style={{ float: "right" }}>
              Test link in helper
            </a>
          </FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```